# How to get open connections statistics without ss or netstat

Tags: kernel, tcp, socket, udp

The question may sound silly but I'm trying to make a tool that uses `ss` data. Sadly I'm having some troubles regarding output format parsing (too much randomness depending on version and system).

So, I think I might just get the data without using `ss`.

Basically I need to list TCP and UDP connections.

Columns I'm using are protocol, state, local and peer address/port and users.
After some research I'm not sure where can I get this informations at a lower level.

Any idea ?

Comment: Hi, use netstat instead (deprecated but replaced by ss)

Comment: I think I will still have to deal with various text output parsing problems. I was thinking about something at a lower level.

Answer (score 0):

The `ss` tool is a part of **iproute**. If you want to see how it works, you can download the source code from [here](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/net/iproute2/) and see how they are getting that information at a lower level. This would help you with your development

Comment: Yes I did have a look before, quite heavy to read. But maybe I can use another command to get rawer output or, like I do for active processes, use something like /proc/ ?